# Selecting data from joined tables based on one distinct field but returning all other columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have looked through many previous questions but can't seem to find one that matches my query?

My current site has customer details stored across different tables within the database.

I have managed to join the tables based on Firstname and Lastname with:

```
Select * 
FROM ps_customer
INNER JOIN ps_address
      ON ps_address.Firstname = ps_customer.Firstname AND   
         ps_address.Lastname = ps_customer.Lastname
```

However, the results contain duplicated email addresses for the same customers. What I wanted was to do was return all columns from the joined tables but only for distinct/unique email address? is there a command that can do this?

ps I'm very new to sql, so apologies for nontechnical language

I wanted to do something like in this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2qmu.png)

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Comment: if the customer has more than 1 postage, you need to tell the  query which row to pick with an aggregate function like min or max on a date/time, otherwise it will pick both rows and you'll end up with duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pc.ID,
    pc.Firstname,
    pc.Lastname,
    pa.Address1,
    pa.Address2,
    pa.Zip,
    pc.email
FROM ps_customer pc
INNER JOIN ps_address pa
    ON pa.Firstname = pc.Firstname AND
       pa.Lastname = pc.Lastname;
```

I don't know exactly which columns you want to select, but the above pattern should be one way to go here.

Comment: Thanks! thats worked but I probably haven't presented my question very clearly. What i wanted was to select all fields from the two joined tables but only have one row of data for each email as there is duplicated emails for the same customer, where they may have entered a different postage address

Comment: @AndyL I don't think my query changes based on your new data.

Comment: Thanks again. However, Is there a way of selecting all column fields from the joined tables but omitting only the rows where there is a duplication in just one column such as email?

Comment: Please show us some data.  I can imagine several result sets which you might have in mind.